# What's the absolutely lightest app to burn audio CD from FLAC files for Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording, optical-media, flac

Could somebody recommend absolutely lightest app to burn audio CD from FLAC files for Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

*u/positive_X*

> cdrtfe

https://mirr.re/d/Yjd

My current favorite!

Answer (score 0):

I use ImgBurn to create audio CDs. There is a guide in their forum on how to do it. It transcodes mp3s to audio CD format so I expect it would do the same for FLAC.